# IntelliJ Ultimate Equivalent of Eclipse Servers Project (Tomcat)?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ *Ultimate* and have a question regarding locally testing a Tomcat app from within the IDE.

I have a `/META-INF/context.xml` file that needs to be deployed with the WAR when it is deployed on our remote Tomcat servers, but because of the way it is setup, this file cannot be used when testing locally.

To handle this in Eclipse, there is a "Servers" project where you can set Tomcat configuration like `context.xml, server.xml, catalina.properties`, etc. that is ONLY used when running the app from within Eclipse.

I didn't see anything similar to this in IntelliJ. Basically what I need is the capability to use a custom `context.xml` when running locally in the IDE and a different `context.xml` when deploying to the real remote servers.

I have a feeling this should be handled in the Tomcat Run Configuration within IntelliJ, but didn't see anything obvious in there.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use IntelliJ Ultimate? IIRC Tomcat integration is only available there, not in Community.

Comment: @DenisKniazhev - I'm using Ultimate. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: I haven't found a direct way of swapping Tomcat configuration either, but you can try to achieve this using `Before Launch` custom action, by either using `Build Artifacts` action or by running a custom maven/gradle task which will start a server with the given configuration.

Comment: You can [customize the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) to include arbitrary files from different locations, it's possible to create 2 artifacts with different context.xml files.